# Comparing one Master Text File with multiple text files and printing the difference in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a working code in python that compares the two text files and prints the difference, however now i need to compare one master file (file1) to multiple files (file 2, file 3...) in the same directory and print the difference

Note: Contents of Master File(file1) will never change

```
For Example:

    File1 has
    boy1
    boy2
    boy3

    File2
    boy1
    boy4
    boy5

    File 3
    boy2
    boy6
    boy7

Desired output 

     #in file1 but not file2
      boy2
      boy3
     #in file1 but not file3
      boy1
      boy3
    ...





Code for comparing two files and printing delta


    with open('file1.txt') as f:
            t1 = f.read().splitlines()
            t1s = set(t1)

        with open('file2.txt') as f:
            t2 = f.read().splitlines()
            t2s = set(t2)

        #in file1 but not file2
        print "Only in file1"
        for diff in t1s-t2s:
            print t1.index(diff), diff

        #in file2 but not file1
        print "Only in file2"
        for diff in t2s-t1s:
            print t2.index(diff), diff
```

Comment: It should simply be a matter of iterating over the secondary files and comparing each to the master in turn. Use a for loop and something like `glob.glob()`, `os.listdir()`, or `os.walk()` to produce the file sequence.

Comment: I tried reading about os.walk() but was not able to integrate it in this code to read all the files